# Auth0 and Firebase token difference (OIDC vs Firebase Tokens)

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, auth0, openid-connect

I am trying to choose between Auth0 and Firebase as my identity provider. I am building a SPA with a Backend API and I would like to use Auth0 or Firebase for all the logic regarding users/passwords/access rights and etc.

Auth0 uses OIDC, which is kinda standard, but IMHO overengineered and very complex. It has separate tokens for identity (ID Token) and for accessing backend resources (access token), whereas firebase uses a single token (if I understand correctly).

So my question here is what authentication mechanism is Firebase using and why a single token is enough in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication uses two token types:

- a long-lived refresh token that identifies the user
- a short-lived ID token that validates that the user has access to the backend services

So it sounds like the two are pretty similar.

Comment: in OIDC, refresh token is a completely different thing and ID token should not be used to access backend services, so it doesn't sound that similar to me :(

Comment: ID tokens can definitely be used to access backend services. Refresh tokens in OAuth and OIDC can be used to refresh ID tokens when they expire.